# Is this manipulation of the Taylor series valid?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

The Taylor series of a function $f(x)$, (assuming differentiability) is:
$$\tag{1}f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2+...$$
If I take $x=x+h$ I get:
$$\tag{2}f(x+h)=f(a)+f'(a)(x+h-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x+h-a)^2+...$$

1. From what I understand, $a$ in above statement can be equal to any value, whichever makes computations easy. But what If I take $a=x$? From eq.(1) I get:
   $$f(x)=f(x)+f'(x)(x-x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(x-x)^2+....$$
   $$\Rightarrow f(x)=f(x)$$
   Seems valid...?

Now from eq.(1) and eq.(2) I can get:
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(a)-f(a)+f'(a)(x+h-a-(x-a))+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)((x=h-a)^2-(x-a)^2)+...$$
$$\tag{3}\Rightarrow f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(a)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(h^2+2h(x-a))+...$$

2. Now in eq.(3) can I replace $a$ with $x$ like this:
   $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(h^2+2h(x-x))+...$$
   to get
   $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(h^2)+...$$

Are the manipulations in **1.** and **2.** valid? What would be the underlying conditions be for them to be valid?

---

For the above function $f(x), f:R\to R$. I'm assuming $f(x)$ is differentiable $\forall x$, and $h$ is just a constant.

Comment: Note that your final equation is the same as Eq (1) with $x = a+h$: $f(a+h) - f(a) = f'(a)h + \ldots$. If you use $x$ or $a$ as the variable name does not matter here.

Comment: Interesting, I had not noticed that...But can I take $x=a$ is essentially my doubt I guess.

Comment: You can, because the equation holds for all real $a$ (at which $f$ is infinitely differentiable) and $x$. At least that’s what I think.

Comment: The problem is this: you start by writing a formula involving $x,a,f$ without stating the conditions under which it is valid. If you start by saying "suppose $f$ is a function such that for all $x,a$ the following holds" then you may stick in whatever $a,x$ you please. But usually Taylor's Theorem starts with an assumption about $a$ and restricts the $x$'s you may use in some way: so in real life your chase round the formulas is not going to be the way to prove your final statement.

Comment: @Tavish if this is about real variable having all derivatives at $a$ does not necessarily mean that the Taylor series sums to the value of the function (there are non-zero functions with $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$ so the OP ought to be saying exactly what the hypotheses are.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you give an example of a non-zero function with all derivatives zero at zero but the Taylor series doesn’t sum to its value?

Comment: That is a question, not a comment @Tavish  ;-). Try $f$ defined by $f(0):=0$, otherwise $f(x):=\exp{(-\frac{1}{x^2})}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Nice. And what’s stopping me from asking questions in the comments ;)

Comment: It was more of an open question as to when is taking $x=a$ valid / not valid in the Taylor series formula. I just wanted to find a way to get the final equation....For the above $f(x)$, $f:R\to R$. I'm assuming it is differentiable at every $x$ and $h$ is a constant.

Comment: It is perhaps useful to use a different notation to understand what you are really doing. Instead of writing $f(x) = f(a) + \ldots$ lets denote the Taylor polynomial of $f$ expanded about $a$ by $T_f(x,a)$. Now if this series converges to the function then obviously $T_f(x,a) = f(x)$, but this notation is more useful to see what is going on. Taking $a=x$ would then give us $T_f(x,x) = f(x)$ which is just telling you that if you make a Taylor series about a point $x$ and then evaluate the series at that point you get the exact result which is of course true.